# Importing/exporting modules issues after updating Angular from 12 to 15, and JS version from ES2015 to ES2022

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack

I'm running out of ideas how to solve problems with importing classes/interfaces/services.

Basically I'm gettin dozens of warning like this after upgrade to Angular 15 from 12 (with the guide):

```
WARNING in ./libs/data-models/src/lib/data-models.ts 87:0-1770
export 'ILights' (reexported as 'ILights') was not found in './models/entities/lights_ifc' (module has no exports)
```

And `ILights` is nothing more than just a simple interface:

```
export interface ILights {
  pk: number;
  timeUpdated: Date;
  lightId: string;
  groupName: string | null;
  type: LightsType;
  state: LightsState;
}
```

These are warnings but I also got this kind of error:

```
C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:843
/* harmony export */   "AlarmsRepository": () => (/* binding */ AlarmsRepository)
                                                                ^
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AlarmsRepository' before initialization
    at Module.AlarmsRepository (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:843:65)
    at Object../apps/api/src/alarms/alarms.service.ts (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\webpack:\web-app-random-name\apps\api\src\alarms\alarms.service.ts:48:83)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\webpack:\web-app-random-name\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../apps/api/src/gateway/message.queue.ts (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:7216:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\webpack:\web-app-random-name\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../apps/api/src/rabbitmq/rabbitmqFpi.provider.ts (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:11803:84)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\webpack:\web-app-random-name\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../apps/api/src/alarms/alarms.repository.ts (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:849:92)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\webpack:\web-app-random-name\webpack\bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object../apps/api/src/airplanes/airplanes.repository.ts (C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\Work\web_gui\dist\apps\api\main.js:291:87)
No errors found.
```

and this is the line from the logs, it's pointing to constructor element that it looks like this because previously we had circural dependecies issues:

```
@Inject(forwardRef(() => AlarmsRepository)) private readonly alarmRepository: AlarmsRepository
```

Maybe I'm using wrong ES versions but I'm not sure about it.. More details here:

Angular:

```
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1500.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      15.0.4
@angular-devkit/core               15.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         15.0.4
@angular/cdk                       15.0.3
@angular/material                  15.0.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   15.0.3
@schematics/angular                15.0.4
rxjs                               7.8.0
typescript                         4.8.4
webpack                            5.75.0
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["ES2021", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "paths": {
      //paths are here
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}
```

and before update it was:

```
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
```

Do you have any ideas or tips that could help me with solving this errors?

Comment: `@Inject(forwardRef(() => AlarmsRepository)) private readonly alarmRepository!: AlarmsRepository` try adding exclamation after variable name

Comment: Unfortunately such a statement is not correct for my IDE